# Show submit button if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to hide the submit button if none checkboxes is checked.
if at least one is checked the submit button should be displayed.
I use JQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="2">

<input type="submit" id="submit_prog" value='Submit' />
```

EDIT

How can I combine it with a "check all" checkbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $submit = $("#submit_prog").hide(),
        $cbs = $('input[name="prog"]').click(function() {
            $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
        });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QMtey/1/

The [`.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) accepts a boolean for whether to show or hide.

Comment: Sir, I really liked your way! nice way of thinking !

Comment: Would you do it in your project?

Comment: Wow! This is simple and elegant! Can you explain a little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @zerkms - Would I do _what_ in my project? Probably the answer is "yes", though I simplified my original answer when I remembered that `.toggle()` can (optionally) accept a boolean parameter.

Comment: @nnnnnn: your original answer was awfully unreadable, don't you think so?

Comment: @zerkms - I think the original was definitely harder to read than an if/else, but in the context of a very short function I don't find that sort of thing difficult to follow so I would use it in a real project. In a hypothetical longer function that does more things I would probably use an if/else. Fortunately `.toggle()` solves that issue, as I eventually remembered.

Answer (score 6):

I'll do you one better! You can do this with just css.

```
input[type=submit] {
  display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ input[type=submit] {
  display:block;
}
```

Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wASK/

Comment: @Frederik: good luck debugging it after you change layout a bit

Comment: @zerkms given that the selector would be dissociated from the layout (ie: a className for this feature), I think it can work flawlessly

Comment: @antony and zerkms I agree with both of you. Fredrik has the best answer and he should get the +15 but this is just a different approach to the problem

Comment: @StefanFrederiksen Yup, as [css-tricks puts it](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) This is "all good-to-go in IE 8 and up"

Answer (score 2):

with the following code when the user check some the button will appear and when uncheck all it will hide again.

```
jQuery('[name="prog"]').click(function(){
    if (jQuery('[name="prog"]:checked').length > 0)    
        jQuery('#submit_prog').show();
    else jQuery('#submit_prog').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

$checkboxes.on('change', function() {
   $('#submit_prog').prop('disabled', !($checkboxes.length == $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length));
});
```

The idea is that you JavaScript to check if the amount of checkboxes matches the amount of checked checkboxes. The ! flips it and sets the submit button's disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="prog"]').change(function(){
    var submitBtn=$('#submit_prog');
    if ($('input[name="prog"]:checked').length > 0) {
        submitBtn.show();
    } else {
        submitBtn.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle to hide and show the element.

```
$("input[name='prog']").on("change",function(){
        $("#submit_prog").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    if (n > 1) {
      $("#Should_Be_Same_ID").removeClass('hide');
    }
    else {
      $("#Should_Be_Same_ID").addClass('hide'); 
    }
  };
  countChecked();

  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display : none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br />
<br /><input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="1" id="checked">
<label for="checked"> Checked me
</label>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" class="hide" id="Should_Be_Same_ID" value='Submit' />
```